# Cannot find creation.component module

Tags: angular

I booted up my angular project this morning and I'm getting the error message

```
ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts(10,35): error TS2307: Cannot find module 
'./creation/creation.component'.
src/app/app.module.ts(19,5): error TS2304: Cannot find name 
'creationComponent'
```

How would I go about fixing this I know I need to create the file but where, and does it require .ts?

Comment: Kindly post your folder structure

Comment: I'm quite new and not sure how to do this using latex, but here is a screen grab: https://gyazo.com/0ab883d5b0c71c4c22789716a759e7e6

Comment: i do not see anywhere file/folder named creation in that image

Comment: I created the file creation within the app file, then created a sub file called creation.component but it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: if you've created it should lie within the folder. since that is not there error is obvious

Comment: Here is proof the issue still persists despite adding the folder/files.
https://gyazo.com/8a557b5246777eaadda36b64b097395d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having a folder inside app , you should be able to import with the following code,

```
import {CreationComponent} from './creation/creation.component';
```

If you get any comilation errors, you can use the Vscode's great support to fix them using auto fix or use Format document by right clicking on the code

do a npm start once you do the changes